# Copying specific ranges from one excel file and distribute them into their appropriate sheets in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table in the "Source" file, range: AG5:AN5,AG6:AN6...AG16:AN16 and my task is to copy these data and paste them in the appropriate sheets in another "Destination" workbook with 12 sheets in it. Each sheet has the name. Although the range in the source workbook doesn't change, the data contained there changes on daily basis. Therefore these data should be copied not in one fixed cell but should slide down based on last filled-in cell. Copying range in the destination file will be started from "C6" and down. I did record macros and made small corrections but the problem is that when this task is performed workbooks are activated several times and it has a blinking effect. Is it possible to use loop in this example and how can I avoid activation of workbooks during copy-paste operation?

"GL Rates Calculation.xlsm" - Source file
"DPR_ALS_September_2017.xlsx" - Destination file

Here's my code:

```
Sub GL_DPR_FillIn()

    Range("AG5:AN5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("DPR_ALS_September_2017.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Ch24").Select
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("C" & lastRow + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Windows("GL Rates Calculation.xlsm").Activate
    Range("AG6:AN6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("DPR_ALS_September_2017.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Ch30").Select
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("C" & lastRow + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Windows("GL Rates Calculation.xlsm").Activate
    Range("AG7:AN7").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("DPR_ALS_September_2017.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Ch54").Select
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("C" & lastRow + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Windows("GL Rates Calculation.xlsm").Activate
    Range("AG8:AN8").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("DPR_ALS_September_2017.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Ch56").Select
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("C" & lastRow + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Windows("GL Rates Calculation.xlsm").Activate
    Range("AG9:AN9").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("DPR_ALS_September_2017.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Ch60 ").Select
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("C" & lastRow + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Windows("GL Rates Calculation.xlsm").Activate
    Range("AG10:AN10").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("DPR_ALS_September_2017.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Ch62").Select
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("C" & lastRow + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Windows("GL Rates Calculation.xlsm").Activate
    Range("AG11:AN11").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("DPR_ALS_September_2017.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Ch65").Select
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("C" & lastRow + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Windows("GL Rates Calculation.xlsm").Activate
    Range("AG12:AN12").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("DPR_ALS_September_2017.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Ch67").Select
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("C" & lastRow + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Windows("GL Rates Calculation.xlsm").Activate
    Range("AG13:AN13").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("DPR_ALS_September_2017.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Ch117").Select
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("C" & lastRow + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Windows("GL Rates Calculation.xlsm").Activate
    Range("AG14:AN14").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("DPR_ALS_September_2017.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Ch123").Select
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("C" & lastRow + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Windows("GL Rates Calculation.xlsm").Activate
    Range("AG15:AN15").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("DPR_ALS_September_2017.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Ch51").Select
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("C" & lastRow + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Windows("GL Rates Calculation.xlsm").Activate
    Range("AG16:AN16").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("DPR_ALS_September_2017.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Ch124").Select
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("C" & lastRow + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows("GL Rates Calculation.xlsm").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: I've posted a working revision. The previous post had errors. This one is tested and runs nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try and let me know if you have any problems.

```
Sub GL_DPR_FillIn()

Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim wbB As Workbook
Dim wsName, lastRow
Dim j

Set wbA = Workbooks("GL Rates Calculation.xlsm") 'This one should already be open
Set wbB = Workbooks.Open("C:\pathname\DPR_ALS_September_2017.xlsx")  'Open the destination workbook

For j = 5 To 16 Step 1

    wbA.Worksheets("GL").Range("AG" & j & ":" & "AN" & j).Copy

        If j = 5 Then wsName = "Ch24"
        If j = 6 Then wsName = "Ch30"
        If j = 7 Then wsName = "Ch54"
        If j = 8 Then wsName = "Ch56"
        If j = 9 Then wsName = "Ch60"
        If j = 10 Then wsName = "Ch62"
        If j = 11 Then wsName = "Ch65"
        If j = 12 Then wsName = "Ch67"
        If j = 13 Then wsName = "Ch117"
        If j = 14 Then wsName = "Ch123"
        If j = 15 Then wsName = "Ch51"
        If j = 16 Then wsName = "Ch124"


       lastRow = Worksheets(wsName).Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
       Worksheets(wsName).Range("C" & lastRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Next j
'To Close the Destination Workbook, uncomment the following line
'wbB.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks for the advice. I don't know where the 2 came from. I started out using .lastRow (which was wrong) and .Sheets (which was ok) but found out it worked without the period, so I went with it. I just couldn't figure out how to get around the different sheet names because they weren't in succession. Regards bro.

Comment: Thanks. But VBA find error (run time error '-2147352565(80020006)) in the following line wbA.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & j & ":" & "N" & j).Copy ...I tried to change range letters as "AG" and "AN", thinking that you missed "A"s but anyway doesn't work.

Comment: @Nurzhan, I thought you would have enough sense to change "Sheet1" to whatever **your** sheetname is called. I tested this many times, and it works just fine.

Comment: Yes, I did so, I changed "sheet1"  to "GL", as per our instruction but the above-mentioned error appears.

Comment: @Nurzhan You were right about the "A"s. I've also changed "Sheets" to "Worksheets". Whatever error you are getting, is in the naming, because I'm getting it to work consistently with my names. **Give this one a try**

Comment: Thank you Mitch for trying to help me. But the problem continues. Here's the line which VBA sees as error(copied directly):

wbA.Worksheets("GL").Range("AG" & j & ":" & "AN" & j).Copy

Comment: Ok, lets see what references you have. **Visual Basic For Applications**, ** Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library**, **OLE Automation**, and **Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library** are the ones I have listed. You can find them in VB applications screen under **Tools/References**.

Comment: Yes, checked. Everything is the same just I have 15 instead of 14.